# Azure DevOps pipeline task NetCoreCLI pack. AutoVersion but keep Major.Minor.Patch unchanged

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, versioning

I have multiple NuGet packages in the same repository. I would like to AutoVersion my packages to $Major.$Minor.$Patch-CI-$DateTimeStamp. $Major.$Minor.$Patch-CI-$rev would also work.

If I know what the original version is, it will make the NuGet package easier to understand. I can also ensure that my dev NuGet packages are a higher version than my master NuGet packages. I don't want to manually set the Major, Minor, and Patch variables because there are multiple NuGet packages in the solution.

The following attempt always has Major.Minor.Patch as 1.0.0

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: $(projectsNuGet)
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: 'byPrereleaseNumber'
```

This doesn't change the version at all

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNetCoreCLI pack !master
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: $(projectsNuGet)
    nobuild: true
    arguments: --version-suffix pre9999
```

Comment: The `arguments` input seems to be ignored. But try `buildProperties: VersionSuffix=pre9999`. The `--version-suffix` option to [`dotnet pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) is documented to define the value of the VersionSuffix MSBuild property and the [implementation of the DotNetCoreCLI task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/78fcd0700d23f9a5b1b8357392197a95b14c4ad1/Tasks/DotNetCoreCLIV2/packcommand.ts#L166) is clear about passing the values of `buildProperties` to MSBuild as properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure DevOps pipeline task NetCoreCLI pack. AutoVersion but keep Major.Minor.Patch unchanged

You should defined the Major, Minor, and Patch as variables in the YAML file and pass them as arguments for the task `DotNetCoreCLI`:

```
variables:
  Major: '1'
  Minor: '0'
  Patch: '0'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: $(projectsNuGet)
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#package-versioning) is the documentation that gives a good set of yaml examples.

If there are multiple NuGet packages in the solution, you could defined different Major, Minor and Patch for each project, like `Major_Project1: '1'`, then pass it as argument `majorVersion: '$(Major_Project1)'`.

Alternatively, if you do not want to defined Major, Minor, and Patch as variables in the YAML file manually, you could your second method, but there is a little different.

We need add below `VersionPrefix` and `VersionSuffix` properties in the project file .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.3</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Then we need use the DotNetCoreCLI **custom** donet task instead of nuget `pack` task with argument `--version-suffix "pre9999"`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    projects: '$(projectsNuGet)'
    custom: pack
    nobuild: true
    arguments: '--version-suffix "pre9999"'
```

[image]

Comment: (1)  I added to the top of the pipeline name: '$(Date:MMddyyyy)-$(Rev:r)' so I could use the variable $(Build.BuildNumber) to get a timestamp-dependent --version-suffix
(2) Packages are now created in the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) instead of $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)